# R - Adding grep Return Values

Tags: r

I want to search a list of strings in a comments Column and count the number of strings that are found. The sample code is as below -

```
> count = grep('abc','abcdefghijklmnop') + grep('ijk','abcdefghijklmnop') + grep('mno','abcdefghijklmnop')
> count
[1] 3
> typeof(count)
[1] "integer"
> str(count)
 int 3
```

Now i can use count for further activities. But when one string is not found, i don't get the correct count.

```
> count = grep('abc','abcdefghijklmnop') + grep('ijk','abcdefghijklmnop') + grep('xyz','abcdefghijklmnop')
> count
integer(0)
> typeof(count)
[1] "integer"
> str(count)
 int(0)
```

I need a ***count = 2*** here instead of 0

`as.vector( grep('xxx','abcdefghijklmnop') )` -- Dosent Work

My requirement is count so i cannot use grepl.Is there a solution to fix this?

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Try `library(stringi) ; stri_count_regex('abcdefghijklmnop','abc|ijk|xyz')`

Comment: This works. Thanks. Want to post as answer? Although i am not able to figure out why the conversion to vector does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
length(gregexpr("abc|ijk|mno",'abcdefghijklmnop')[[1]])
[1] 3
length(gregexpr("abc|ijk|xyz",'abcdefghijklmnop')[[1]])
[1] 2
```

Comment: Works Fine. Thanks!  I would really want to find the issue with conversion from number to Vector.